# Grouping by date in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53
            [product] => something
            [price] =>  £78
            [quantity] => 23
            [time] => 2011-07-15 20:29:21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 52
            [product] => product
            [price] => £89
            [quantity] => 1
            [time] => 2011-07-14 00:51:57
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 51
            [product] => product
            [price] => £89
            [quantity] => 1
            [time] => 2011-07-14 00:51:37
        ))
```

I got this using the following sql statement:

```
select * from some_table GROUP BY time DESC
```

I want to display the results ordered by date, with the date as a heading:

e.g.

```
**2011-07-15**
all array elements for above date go here

**2011-07-15**
all array elements for above date go here
```

I thought about doing a seperate statement for each seperate day, but that sounds wrong. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORDER BY Time in your query, like this:

```
select * from some_table ORDER BY time DESC
```

Then loop in PHP:

```
$last_date = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['time']));
    if($date != $last_date)
        echo '**'.$date.'**';
    $last_date = $date;
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Id: '.$row['Id'];
    echo 'Product: '.$row['product'];
    echo 'Price: '.$row['price'];
    echo 'Quantity: '.$row['quantity'];
    echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

If you're ouputting to a console instead of an HTML page then replace the `'<br \>'` with `"\n"`

Comment: GROUP BY and ORDER BY are two different things. GROUP BY will only have an affect if more than one tuple in your table has the same time and you are selecting aggregate data like SUM(quantity) or something

Comment: Also, store the last date('Y-m-d') in a var and display the date header only if the date changes.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice he wanted each date to only be outputted once. I'll update my post. Thanks

Comment: I already have the result, so I don't need to do `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` (I've build a wrapper function for this), I'm using a foreach($result_array as $item) statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$arrDate = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53
            [product] => something
            [price] =>  £78
            [quantity] => 23
            [time] => 2011-07-15 20:29:21
        );


$currentDate = null;

foreach ($arrDate as $item) {

      if ($item["time"] == $currentDate) {
          // print details
      }
      else {
           $currentDate = $arrDate["time"];
           // print date header.
           // print details
      } 

}

?>
```